# how to get progress bar percentage in a textblock to work?

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I have a stored procedure that selects from the database and populates a datagrid. I am trying to show that process in a progress bar. I have managed to make the progress bar work as expected, but I am having difficulties showing the process percentage. I know where I am wrong, but I just don't know how to fix it. I am setting the `progressBar.Maximum` to dt.Rows.Count.And that is why I get for an example 4% at the end,because I have 4 items in my database.I tried putting it it a for loop where my i goes from zero to dt.Rows.Count in the doWork instead of 100, but that doesn't work.

this is my code:

```
private void bSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
      //  int i = 0;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("tblProbaSelect", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter puname = new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        puname.Value = tbUsername.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(puname);

        try
        {
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            progressBar.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar.Maximum = 100;
            double step = (100 / ((double)dt.Rows.Count));v

           /*
            for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                progressBar.Value += 1;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
               // MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
            }*/
            tabela.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }



    }
    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            progressBar.Value += step;
            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

EDIT: I have managed to get the percentage from 0 to 100.But it isn't really based on a database query.
The changes I have made is that that I have put my select method in a function,and I am calling that function in a doWork part.But still,my progress value is based on a for value,not the query itself.
my new code:

```
  public void selectQ()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("tblProbaSelect", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter puname = new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();


        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            puname.Value = tbUsername.Text;


        }));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(puname);
        try
        {
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                progressBar_Copy.Minimum = 0;
                progressBar.Maximum = 100;
                double step = (100 / ((double)dt.Rows.Count));


            }));


          this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
               // Thread.Sleep(1000);
                tabela.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            }));

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }


    }
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
          for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
          {
              progressBar.Value += step;
              (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
              Thread.Sleep(100);
          }

        selectQ();
    }
```

Comment: X% = (i * 100.0 / Count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
progressBar.Maximum = 100;
double step = (100 / ((double)dt.Rows.Count));
```

and inside the for cycle

```
progressBar.Value += step; //At the very last step round to 100
```

Comment: I have putted it inside the doWork for and it works the same as it did

Comment: @Alexander doWork will update the progress bar once on each 100 milliseconds. You will need to update the progress bar when you have some progress. I am not entirely in context with your project, therefore I am having difficulty what progress is in your case. Can you elaborate on when should the progress bar be updated?

Comment: I am using it to show progress while I am fetching data with an sql select statement and showing it in a datagrid

Comment: @Alexander which is the event which should trigger a progress event?

Comment: selectQ(); is the event

Comment: @Alexander you call it after you refresh the progress bar. You will need to call it during the event.

Comment: I need to put the for in the selectQ?Does it matter where?

Comment: @Alexander it is not the position of the for what matters. The problem you have is that you are running a cycle to refresh the progress bar, a cycle which ends before the job it is supposed to monitor even starts. To remedy this situation, you will need to trigger progress bar status when actual progress happens. If you fill the table with a single function, then it will be atomic, which will defeat the purpose of a progress bar. However, if you fill the table line by line according to your result, then you can update the progress bar for each line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't know the progress of this operation until it's complete. In order to get the progress bar maximum, you must have all your records. If you have all your records, then the job is already done.
You could pre-query to get the row count then use the DataTable.RowChanged event to know when the data adapter has added a new row to the table, but you would be doing the long running operation (the SQL query) twice, just so your progress bar works **DON'T DO THAT**!

I would suggest you use an indeterminate progress bar and turn it's visibility on and off. Just set the IsIndeterminate property of the progress bar to true either in xaml or code behind:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar_Copy" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
```

or

```
progressBar_Copy.IsIndeterminate = true;
```

You should use using blocks for your disposable objects too. I've written you a sample.

```
    void ExecuteQuery()
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        progressBar_Copy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(tbUsername.Text);
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        string username = e.Argument as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("tblProbaSelect", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                        e.Result = dt;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        e.Result = ex;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result is Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(((Exception)e.Result).Message);
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable dt = e.Result as DataTable;
            if (dt != null)
                tabela.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        }

        progressBar_Copy.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

Comment: I have managed to create the indeterminated progress bar,I wanted to see if I could make one with the percenteges

Comment: Well as I stated, you'd need to do the query twice. Once to get the row count, then, when you did it the second time, hook up to the DataTable.RowChanged event and call the worker progress changed to update the percentage. You'd do double the work just to have a working progress bar.